# how to convert dataframe to rdd(key string, json string) in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created dataframe from json below.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("my.json")
```

after that, I would like to create a rdd(key,JSON) from a Spark dataframe. 
I found df.toJSON.
However, it created rdd[string].

i would like to create rdd[string(key), string(JSON)].
how to convert spark data frame to rdd(string(key), string(JSON)) in spark.

my dataframe looks like below.

```
 root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- data1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- data2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- data3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- image: string (nullable = true)
 |-- flag: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: can you show how your Spark dataframe looks like?

Comment: @sean kim: you can use `.rdd` method on `df`.

Comment: @sean kim: if you are using Spark 1.6 or above use `DataSet` api to convert df to RDD easily

Comment: Just one question what are you trying to use as the Key and as the json can you please provide an example ! Would be helpful for us to help you out !

Comment: key is one of columns and json is whole contents of dataframe row. for example, key:id, json:{id:xxx, name:xxx. image:xxx, flag:xxx}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a solution, although i don't know what's your use case, because if you want to extract the id as key to distinguish json file i think you can just filter on the id column on you dataframe. Anyway following method can satisfy your request:

test json file: test.json

```
{"id": "1","data": "data1","image": "image1"}
{"id": "2","data": "data2","image": "image2"}
```

scala codes (withColumn + udf + json4s):

```
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, MappingException}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def getJsonKey(jsonstring: String): (String) = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val parsedJson = parse(jsonstring)  
    val key = (parsedJson \ "id").extract[String]
    key
}
val getJsonKeyUDF = udf((jsonstring: String) => getJsonKey(jsonstring))

val df = spark.read.format("text").load("test.json")
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{"id": "1","data"...|
|{"id": "2","data"...|
+--------------------+

val newDF = df.withColumn("key", getJsonKeyUDF(df("value")))
              .withColumn("json", df("value"))
              .select("key", "json")
newDF.show
+---+--------------------+
|key|                json|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|{"id": "1","data"...|
|  2|{"id": "2","data"...|
+---+--------------------+

newDF.rdd.collect
>> Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([{"id": 1,"data": "data1","image": "image1"},1], [{"id": 2,"data": "data2","image": "image2"},2])
```

## Updated:

If you really want to use rdd finally, there is a even simpler approach:

```
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, MappingException}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val rdd = sc.textFile("test.json")
>> rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

val newRDD = rdd.map(jsonstring => {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val parsedJson = parse(jsonstring)  
    val key = (parsedJson \ "id").extract[String]
    (key, jsonstring)
   })
>> newRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]

newRDD.collect
Array[(String, String)] = Array((1,{"id": "1","data": "data1","image": "image1"}), (2,{"id": "2","data": "data2","image": "image2"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Linbo's answer somewhat, SparkSQL already has UDFs to extract json fields:

```scala
  import sqlc.implicits._
  val rdd = sc.textFile("example.json")
    .toDF("json")
    .selectExpr("get_json_object(json,'$.id')","json")
    .map{ row => (row.getString(0),row.getString(1)) }
```